# How to enforce numerical precision throughout a package

Tags: numerics

I developed a big package that does quite a bit of numerics. Is there a way to enforce that all numerical computations are done with a pre-defined accuracy? For example, can one use something like SetAccuracy[...] in the beginning of the package and then all functions automatically use that accuracy. Of course, one can wrap all functions with N[], but I wonder if that can be avoided.

EDIT: As an example, I tried changing

```
BeginPackage["packageName`"];
...
```

into

```
BeginPackage["packageName`"];
$MaxPrecision=10;
...
```

but I noticed that the computations are still done with unlimited precision (unless N[] is used to wrap expressions).

Comment: Well, maybe. But this is not how *Mathematica* is meant to work and I would question whether it is a good idea to have a package that relies on a non-standard use of numerics. Can you give an example that shows your use case more clearly?

Comment: (Also, your `$MaxPrecision` is by no means localized to the package, so this will be problematic for the user.)

Comment: I understanding your point. I know that Mathematica is meant to work as it does. However, the question is not about that. In fact, one should be able to use it to solve heavy numerical problems, and I am doing that frequently. The example you seek is way too big to be listed here, but I can simplify. Imagine a piece of code that evolves a network of electronic elements. Basically an ODE system that needs to be solved numerically. Of course, I am doing it in a very specific way so I cannot really use built in ODE solver. The point is, well, as the question states.

Comment: Okay. And you need to do it in fixed precision why exactly? Is it for performance or algorithmic reasons?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that you seem to have decided on the solution and want to know how to implement it. You might be absolutely correct in this decision, but from your question it's hard to tell. If you give us more detail about your use case, it might turn out that someone knows a better way to do what you want than forcing the use of fixed precision.

Comment: thanks for looking into this! no, you missunderstood. The solution is already implemented, and I dare say, without false modesty, probably I am using the best way to do it. The only problem is that I realized that Mathamatica is using infinite precision in all computations (a lot of matrix operations and list operations, no wonder I suppose). Of course, I can go on and put explict N statements whenever needed. The problem is, the package is very big. I would like to avoid it if possible. But, I guess, if there was such a way, someone would have suggested it already.

Comment: I understood that you've already written the package. But to say it bluntly, what you're asking for (restriction to fixed precision numerical arithmetic only, localized to a specific package) is simply impossible in the abstract, because *Mathematica* does not support that, even at a conceptual level. To give people a chance of suggesting an implementation that works for you, it would be necessary for you to give at least some concrete detail about the structure of your package and the numerical requirements of your calculations. I understand this must be getting frustrating for you, but I ...

Comment: ... really don't think that the question admits a good answer as it is currently. FWIW, I personally would use `N`/`SetPrecision` in the appropriate places (e.g. for user-supplied inputs) and take advantage of the reduction of values to the lowest common precision in arithmetic operations. Of course some analysis of numerical stability would also be necessary to properly understand the effect on the calculation of changing the working precision, but this is highly specific to the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is not possible! Exactly an answer I needed. It was yes/no and now I know it is no (can't be done). I have to climb down into the mines and start fixing it the hard way. I just wanted to be sure of it. Well, such is life.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.: To make it more transparent, I just quoted your statement that it is not possible to do this, and indicated it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Oleksandr R: "...what you're asking for (restriction to fixed precision numerical arithmetic only, localized to a specific package) is simply impossible in the abstract, because Mathematica does not support that, even at a conceptual level."